# Swagger.net - how to specify UI notes in the xml comments

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I just started using swagger for the first time and can't seem to figure out how to get the implementation notes to display anything through the Xml Documention comments.

I have scoured the documentation for several hours without seeing any mention of how to populate the specific fields in the json output.

I want this done dynamically and don't want to have to create a static json file for this data 
is there a tutorial or additional documentation on what fields to specify to get certain output.

Also is there a method of displaying a sample json request based from the input models on action methods in the UI output without having to display these by hand

Edit:

Also another problem i have come accross is if i have a simple get method marked as Authorize Swagger UI completely breaks and when i try to add the Authorize header(i am using a Bearer token) to the headers option in the javascript api the authorization token never gets sent 
code is a follows

```
        $(function () {
        window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            discoveryUrl: "/api/swagger",
            dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
            docExpansion: 'list',
            headers: { "Authorization":"Bearer Y2xtY2dyYXRoX2ZhY19jcmRJQ1RHV1MuQ29vcmRpbmF0b3IsRmFjdWx0eS42RC1BMi02Mi03Mi00Qi00Mg=="},
            supportHeaderParams: true,
            supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

        });


        window.swaggerUi.load();

    });
```

when I receive the request in my message handler the authHeader is null and is not present at all in the headers collection and the bearer token has worked fine up until now using Fiddler
is there something going on in the swagger api that i need to do something with that i am missing i have followed the documentation almost exacty to the letter and the function above works fine other than with Authentication and i can not figure out how to populate the Implementation Notes

Answer (score 6):

From the [source code](https://github.com/miketrionfo/Swagger.Net/blob/master/Swagger.Net/XmlCommentDocumentationProvider.cs#L79), it looks like implementation notes are provided by the <remarks/> element of your comments.  For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the resource by the specified ID.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The id.</param>
/// <remarks>These remarks end up in the implementation notes of swagger</remarks>
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "my resource at " + id;
}
```

Comment: I wish swagger-client.js also have Implementaton Notes. only swagger-ui.js has this.